# Could someone look at my html5 and css3?

Tags: html, css

Hey can someone help me with my site?

[http://jsfiddle.net/crazkiller789/5tk6k/]

Im trying to get the links on the side to go to the anchor points through the page.  I am also trying to get the return to top to be inline with the headers they are close to so it does not mess up the line drawn under it.

Could someone help please and thanks.

Comment: Include your code in the question. Your question needs to be self-contained and answerable without depending on links to 3rd party sites.

Comment: @meagar he is using a fiddle, which is appropriate. That being said, the OP should post some code here (CSS and HTML) with the relevant issue.

Comment: @disinfor No, it absolutely is not. JSFiddle can't replace the content of your question. JSFiddle links may *supplement* a question, but they shouldn't be the only useful content in a question.

Comment: No offense to the parliament session of debate here but going through the fiddle...i think its pretty excessive code to paste and all of it is relevant!! :)

Comment: @NoobEditor Then the question doesn't belong on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @NoobEditor All of that code is **most definitely** not relevent. The problem is "I need some text to line up". That means all of the CSS regarding colour, font, radius, etc... is irrelevent

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem** — and **include valid code to reproduce it** — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the side links in your code is you have `<a href="resume.html#Anchor">` You need to remove `resume.html` You're already on that page, you just want the anchor like `#Anchor`. Same with the "return to top" links.

Comment: OK Thanks! Another thing i noticed with the links on the side if you hover over skills the button isnt as big and the whole bar is there a way to fix that?